# How to link libs in netbeans (linux)?

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++

I'm trying to write a program in c++ to analyze sound. I want to use libsndfile library. I added an option -lsndfile  to g++ compiler options. But I get the error:
WavReader.cpp:18: undefined reference to `sf_open'

How to link the library? Please help!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "WavReader.h"
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <iostream>


namespace SA {

    WavReader::WavReader(char* fileName, SoundProcessor* soundProcessor) {
        this->fileName = fileName;
        this->soundProcessor = soundProcessor;
    }

    void WavReader::readFile() {
        SNDFILE* sf = NULL;
        SF_INFO info;
        info.format = 0; 
        sf = sf_open(this->fileName, SFM_READ, &info);

    }

    WavReader::~WavReader() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your compilation command, maybe by finding out what netbeans is doing in your back. Did you consider editing your source with a good editor (emacs) and running the compilation command in a terminal?

Comment: Also note that linker flags need to go to the end of the command line for recent versions of the GNU toolchain.

Comment: It seems you are right, it should be at the end of command line. I removed -lsndfile from "compiler options" and put it to 
project properties -> linker -> libraries -> add option -> another option

and it works now! Netbeans put it to the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

project properties -> linker -> libraries -> add option -> another option:  -lsndfile

Answer (score 2):

You need to link against -lsndfile library...make sure library path are included so it find library from correct location...check /usr/lib/ to make sure it is present on your system, or add path of correct location for your libs...