# Boost date conversion error from/to string

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

#include "boost/date_time.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"

using namespace std;

using namespace boost::gregorian;


int main()

{     

    string s("2001-10-9");

    date d=from_simple_string(s);

    cout << to_simple_string(d) << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

this code gives three errors

> /usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
>
> /usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:49: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'
>
> /usr/include/boost/date_time/date_parsing.hpp:67: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptrabi:cxx11'

i am using netbeans,ubuntu 16.04 , boost 1.58.0, g++ 5.4

What exactly do the errors mean and how can i fix them ?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile, add the flag `-lboost_date_time` to link with the boost date-time library.

There should be a formal way in Netbeans to add a library. Find it, and add `boost_date_time` to get linked against your executable.

Comment: how to add your suggestion with netbeans???

Comment: @AnamulHasan I googled it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040303/how-to-link-libs-in-netbeans-linux

Comment: Thank you very much brother. its finally works.