# Errors with SFML on Netbeans C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, sfml

I'm working on a c++ with Netbeans (on Windows). I'm trying to get SMFL to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600, 800), "TITLE");
    cout << "Hello World!";

    return 0;
}
```

When I launch the application I get the following errors.

```
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
```

Line 31 is

```
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600, 800), "TITLE");
```

I added SFML/include dir to c++ compiler and SFML/lib to linker, can you help me?

EDIT: after retrying to adding lib and include foldes, now I get:
"error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: _I added [...] SFML/lib to linker_ How exactly? Because the linker didn't seem to link all necessary libs. Did you forget OpenGL? Some platforms need that additionally and explicitly for sfml. Happened to me once.

Comment: Was `SFML` that you are using built with `mingw`? I don't think you can use Visual Studio binaries.

Comment: @drescherjm maybe. Which one should I use?

Comment: @nada Project Settings -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories and selected SFML/lib folder. I did nothing with OpenGL, what should I do?

Comment: I believe you have to specify the sfml libraries that you use in addition to the folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm using SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit

Comment: How about using the very nicely written and detailed [tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php) provided on the webpage for exactly this?

Comment: That tutorial is for Visual Studio. @Joe is using `netbeans` and `mingw`. With that said the settings should be similar.

Comment: @drescherjm Right, edited to point at the codeblocks/mingw tutorial.

Comment: @super I tried but that tutorial is not for Netbeans, so I don't know how to import "sfml-graphics", "sfml-window" and "sfml-system"

Comment: @Joe First hit googling [netbeans add link library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040303/how-to-link-libs-in-netbeans-linux).

Comment: that tutorial says to create a DEFINE entry in compiler settings. how can I do that on Netbeans?

Comment: by the way now I get "error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: That means you need to put the dlls in one of the folders of your `PATH`  environment variable or put them in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: This may help with setting the `PATH` environment variable: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I just set C:\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit and C:\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\bin in my PATH environment variable. Nothing changed

Comment: You may have to logout or reboot for the setting to work in your IDE.

Comment: I did it twice. There's something else that needs to be done...

Comment: You will have to debug to figure out what dll is missing. dependency walker should help. Also verify the path is set by typing path in a `cmd.exe` window. Make sure the path is properly separated by `;` characters. Here is a link for dependency walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @drescherjm i checked with cmd.ex. PATH is ok.
I tried with dependency walker but everytime i select the exe file of my application it freezes

Comment: Do you launch your app *inside* the NetBeans (using the "Run" button)?

Comment: @hekto yes i do

Comment: What version of NetBeans? And what type of NetBeans project do you use?

Comment: Netbins 8.2. I selected C/C++ Application

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell NetBeans three things:

- Directory with SFML include files
- Directory with SFML libraries
- List of SFML libraries to link

It looks like you already know how to do #1, but I'll repeat everything just in case. All this setup should be done using the project properties - right-click on your project name, then open the properties setup window. You'll need to make additions in two panes - "C++ Compiler" and "Linker".

The "C++ Compiler" pane is what you need first. Find the line "Include Directories" and click on the square with three points (directory chooser) - then add the SFML "include" directory. This pane in my case is below:

[image: C++ Compiler Setup Pane]

The "Linker" pane is the next one. Find the "Additional Library Directories" and add the SFML "lib" directory - using also the directory chooser. Then find the "Libraries" line and add at least three libraries - "sfml-graphics", "sfml-window" and "sfml-system". For that you need to use slightly more complex chooser, the button you need is "Add Library..." - please see the third picture here. **Order of libraries is important**. This pane in my case is below:

[image: Linker Setup Pane]

This is libraries chooser - use the button "Add Library..."

[image: Libraries Chooser]

Also in your example you need to use prefix "sf::" for SFML types:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 800), "TITLE");
```

**ADDITION**. It looks like (from comments) that compilation and linking problems have been resolved, however the application still couldn't find SFML dynamic libraries. This problem is outside of NetBeans - you just need to make sure, that the SFML directory with dynamic libraries has been added to the Windows system path.

This directory name can be long, so it's easy to mistype it when adding to the path. There is a simple way to verify that - a Windows tool `where.exe`. Some Windows systems don't have this tool - so you can output the current path by the `path` command, and then copy-paste the SFML-related part of the path as an argument to the Unix `ls` command (it's in the MinGW MSYS environment). Normally the `ls` will show you the list of SFML dynamic libraries (with `dll` extension).

Comment: that's exactly what I did, but I always get that error

Comment: Do you mean linkage errors `main.cpp:31: undefined reference to ...`?

Comment: no, sorry. I meant i get this error: "error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Do you have the SFML `bin` directory in your system path? You'll need admin privileges to change it

Comment: my PATH environment variable has the bin directory in it.
I'm not sure about the accesse from my login. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm looking at your comment about how you added SFML to your PATH. It looks like you missed one directory level. The addition should be `C:\SFML-2.5.1-windows-gcc-7.3.0-mingw-64-bit\SFML-2.5.1\bin`