# Setting SFML up with NetBeans in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, sfml

Hi I am having problems with trying to get sfml going with netbeans. Here is a short video of what I have done. [video](https://youtu.be/uunZmFT9-3o)

After listening to HEKTO I now downloaded the MSYS. I removed the static libraries and get this error now:

```
    The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 



This may give some additional information. 

C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tester\dist\Debug\MinGW_1-Windows\tester.exe 

RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,515, total time: 58ms)
```

After adding system path.. heres new img:

[system path img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYjB.png)

Comment: The binaries for mingw should not be named  `.lib`

Comment: At StackOverflow a video is not welcome at all. Remember the purpose of a question is to help readers years from now with the same problem. To achieve this your entire question must be self contained on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please don't use relative paths for SFML - the NetBeans jumps from directory to directory when compiling, so relative paths don't make sense

Comment: @HEKTO changed the C++ include directories path to C:\SFML\include and the Linker additional library directories path to C:\SFML\lib still no change

Comment: Please update your question with copy of what is printed into the Output window

Comment: @HEKTO done hope this helps solve

Comment: @HEKTO I edited the main post. clean and build again. please explain how can i use dynamic ones? because I am unsure what to do with the .dll files

Comment: @HEKTO I followed a question that you answered here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170881/errors-with-sfml-on-netbeans-c-project?rq=1"and noticed your library part looks different then mine? why is that? I have the -d debug files and my release is like yours.

Comment: Congratulations! You've compiled and linked your test. Now add your SFML `bin` directory to the system path

Comment: @HEKTO i updated my post with how I added sfml bin directory to system path. please tell me if its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFML developers recommend the exact match between your MinGW version and your SFML version - please see [this](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/) page, especially these three lines:

```
The compiler versions have to match 100%!
Here are links to the specific MinGW compiler versions used to build the provided packages:
TDM 5.1.0 (32-bit), MinGW Builds 7.3.0 (32-bit), MinGW Builds 7.3.0 (64-bit)
```

Your MinGW compiler is **8.2.0** - it doesn't match. So you'll need to download the MinGW using links from this page and install it manually.

Also you try to link with static libraries (with suffix `_s`). In this case you have to add other libraries to the linker setup - please see [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link-static). If to use dynamic libraries then you won't need any additional libraries, however the SFML directory with its DLLs will need to be added to the **system path**.

**UPDATE**. Your question has been rewritten many times, so my answer has become irrelevant - this is not good, the question can be updated to improve it, but please not to rewrite it completely following additional information given to you in comments. References to videos and pictures aren't welcomed here also. Your question must be self-contained and potentially helpful for others, looking for help in similar situations.

That said I'll add two tips for future generations:

- Don't use relative paths for `include` and `lib` directories in the NetBeans compiler and linker setup - use only absolute paths.
- MinGW distributions, referenced on the SFML downloading [page](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/), don't contain the MSYS (small collection of Unix tools, which includes `make.exe`). You'll need to download and install the MSYS separately, for example using the MinGW installer with `msys-base` package only.

Comment: i downloaded the 7.39 mingw and got new build error please help

Comment: how do I tell netbeans where the make tool is?

Comment: so far so good just need to find out if im doing the .dll files correct? thanks again

Comment: I don't know - do you see any error messages? I mean when running your tester program

Comment: same as last time it build fine then when run it says "The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). "

Comment: Did you do what NetBeans suggested? "Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe) etc."

Comment: Ok i did what netbeans suggested. got a new error " C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tester>gcc main.cpp
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>"

Comment: No, don't compile - just run the program

Comment: I ran the program in cmd using gcc tester.cpp. the output i got was.. "C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tester>gcc main.cpp main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>".

Comment: Don't call gcc - NetBeans already has created the `tester.exe` file for you... Do you see it, by the way? Just run this program

Comment: ok sorry I misunderstood. it says "The code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." is that problem with the compiler?

Comment: No idea about this library... Ask a new question, mentioning the mingw version you have. It's not related to NetBeans

Comment: Thanks for your help its much appreciated. I think I will just drop out uni xD! seems like the wise thing to do

Comment: By the way, "thanks" on this site is expressed by upvoting and/or accepting

Comment: cant upvote. to low level. Also i would check your answer as correct if i was able to accomplish something...