# Undefined reference when using Irrlicht library

Tags: c++, netbeans, linker, undefined, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile the very first code given by Irrlicht library website.

As said in the title, I get an undefined reference. I'm using 8.2 netbeans IDE.

This is what I've done so far : Installed Irrlicht library from the Linux repository (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04). Using these command lines : sudo apt-get install libirrlicht1.8 libirrlicht1.8-dbg libirrlicht-dev libirrlicht-doc

In the "project properties", I've added the include directory, as well as the include headers (e.g all the files contained in /usr/include/irrlicht. Also, in the "Additional Options" (the linker part, I guess ?) , I've seen online that I should add -lIrrlicht command line, and it still got me the undefined reference.

I've tried also the following command line : -L /usr/include/irrlicht -lIrrlicht, still got me the undefined reference.

Note : I'm not able to make any update. Talking about irrlicht, it seems that I have 363 packages outdated. Could the problem be from there ?

Here is the minimum code to see if the Irrlicht library is correctly found by the compiler and correctly linked to the project :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <irrlicht.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace irr;
using namespace core;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    IrrlichtDevice *device=createDevice(video::EDT_SOFTWARE, dimension2d<u32>(640,480),16,false,false,false,0);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, here is what the compiler is prompting :

```
cd '/home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test »
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test »
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
g++ -lIrrlicht    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o : Dans la fonction « main » :
/home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test/main.cpp:26 : référence indéfinie vers « createDevice »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test] Error 1
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test »
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/liam/NetBeansProjects/test »
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I see that I have the following error : "référence indéfinie vers << createDevice >>" which means "undefined reference to << createDevice >> ". So it seems that the problem comes from the command line written in the linker. What command line(s) does the linker expects ?

Comment: Is `Irrlicht` library located in `/usr/include/irrlicht` directory?

Comment: Yes it is. It contains all the header files of irrlicht.

Comment: I didn't ask about the headers, but about the library (binary) you try to link with. It might be in `/usr/lib` directory, for example.

Comment: I used this command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516984/how-to-find-binary-files-in-a-directory to find the binary in
    /usr/include/irrlicht directory.

No results

Comment: The `-lIrrlicht` argument needs to go at the *end* of your command line. It should be in a section called "linker arguments". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040303/how-to-link-libs-in-netbeans-linux) is the first hit I found

Comment: Thanks @Botje ! I was confused between the additionnal command line in the compiler section and the additionnal command line in the linker section. I added -lIrrlicht in compiler, but not in linker. This is why it was not working. Now it builds perfectly !